# Property of magnitude proof

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, order-theory

Is there a way to prove that:

If x < y and y = z, then x < z

I am trying to write a proof for my class but am currently limited to using Euclid's Common Notions and the Axioms for the Real Numbers.

Comment: $y=z$ means $y$ may be replaced with $z$ in any context, no?

Comment: That's a fundamental [substitution property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)#Basic_properties).

Comment: The ancient Greeks didn't use variables, so Euclid's common notions are surely irrelevant. If the axioms for the real numbers you are using are expressed in terms of first-order logic, then the equality rules for first-order logic give what you need.